# How to hide and show table by click on button?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

Here is my `index.html` file :

```
<button id="getAllGroups" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Groups</button>

<div class="container">
    <h2 align="center">LESSONS</h2>
    <table class="table table-dark" border="1" width="100%" cellpadding="5">
        <thead>
        <th>GROUP ID</th>
        <th>GROUP NAME</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbody">

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Below my `js` file:

```
GET: $(document).ready(
function () {

    // GET REQUEST
    $("#getAllGroups").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        ajaxGet();
    });

    // DO GET
    function ajaxGet() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "checkGroups",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.status == "success") {
                     var custList = "";
                    $.each(result.data,
                        function (i, group) {

                            var Html = "<tr>" +
                            "<td>" + group.groupId + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + group.groupName + "</td>" +
                            "</tr>";
                            console.log("Group checking: ", group);
                            $('#tbody').append(Html);
                        });
                    console.log("Success: ", result);

                } else {
                    console.log("Fail: ", result);
                }
            },
                        });
    }
})
```

RestController :

```
@RestController
public class GroupController {
@Autowired
GroupService groupService;
@GetMapping("/checkGroups")
public ResponseEntity<Object> getAllGroups() {
ServiceResponse<List<Group>> response = new ServiceResponse<>("success", groupService.getAll());
return new ResponseEntity<Object>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

My code works but `th` : GROUP ID and GROUP NAME is on page even if I don't click on button `Groups` but I need that my table shows only after click on button.
If I don't click on button, the table should be hidden.

Thanks in advance for responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need that my table shows only after click on button. If I don't click on button, the table should be hidden.

In this case, hide the table when the page loads using CSS and display it when the button is clicked using `show()`:

```css
.container table { display: none; }
```

```js
// in the $.ajax success handler:
let html = result.data.map(g => `<tr><td>${g.groupId}</td><td>${g.groupName}</td></tr>`;
$('#tbody').append(html);
$('.container table').show();
```

Note the simplified and more performant use of `map()` to build your HTML in the above sample.